# Google Cloud Function - Incorrect Content-type text/plain

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I have a cloud function that is created to update a field value in my Firestore database. Cloud function look something like this:

```js
export const resetUser = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const userId = req.body;

      if (!userId) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "permission-denied",
          "Insufficent permissions."
        );
      }

      await db.doc(`users/${userId}`).update({ status: null });

      res.status(200).send({
        error: false,
        message: "success!",
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: true,
        message: err.message,
      });
    }
  }
);
```

This cloud function has been deployed to Google Cloud and I call it through my React app as such:

```
navigator.sendBeacon(
    "https://url-to.cloudfunctions.net/resetUser",
    userId
);
```

Here I'm using `navigator.sendBeacon()` because I have set a `documentListener` where if it's hidden, then it will call this `navigator.sendBeacon()` and send a HTTP request to the link stated together with a `body` which is a `string` stored in a variable called `userId`.

However, this produces an error when I open my log to test this cloud function. It states that `Request has incorrect content-type. text/plain` coupled with `Invalid request, unable to process.` How do I fix this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you specified Request type as String as described [here]https://blog.logrocket.com/rest-api-firebase-cloud-functions-typescript-firestore/#:~:text=create%20our%20Request%20type%3A)

Comment: FYI, I tried in my test environment and I do receive a correct string value in the Cloud Function if I pass a string as second argument of `sendBeacon()`.